# Convergence of a sequence $(1-xn)/(1+xn)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $x\in[0,\infty)$ and a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ given by  $$\frac{1-xn}{1+xn}$$ Show that the sequence converges and determine the limit as a function of $x$.

**Attempt**

I do know the definition for convergence but not sure on how to (or even if to) use it to show convergence here. Do I have to reduce my $n$ (I know that doesn't *show* anything, though)? Is there any test to use that I am not seeing which I can use and then argue for $x$ in the given interval?

Comment: Rewrite the fraction as $$\frac{(1/n)-x}{(1/n)+x} $$

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$, then this is trivial, as $a_n(x)=1$.

Notice that for $x\neq 0$, $$\begin{align*}
a_n(x)
&=\frac{1-xn}{1+xn}\\
&=\frac{1+xn-xn-xn}{1+xn}\\
&=1-\frac{2xn}{1+xn}\\
&=1-\frac{2x}{(1/n)+x}\end{align*}$$
so we clearly have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n(x)=1-\frac{2x}{x}=-1 $$

Comment: So as a function of $x$ the sequence is actually just $-1$?

Comment: @user879295 what about $x=0$ ?

Comment: Yes I see.. That would be $1/1=1$. Then I don't see how we can find the limit as a function of $x$. Would it just be piecewise?

Comment: @user879295 Yes it would be piece-wise. You say $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n(x)=-1$ if else.

Comment: $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 1& x =0\\ 
 -1 & x>0
\end{matrix}\right.$ like this?

Comment: @user879295 i believe in your case, it should be $x>0$, but yes. that is correct. note also that it did not matter whether or not $x$ was positive or negative for the limit to be $-1$, it just had to be non-zero.

Comment: Yes of course. That is my mistake. Thanks a lot that cleared it. When it is stated to show it converges - do you think this is enough? I.e not a formal proof?

Comment: @user879295 it depends on how rigorous you need to be. if you need to show an epsilon-delta proof, then no, this is not enough.

Comment: I am not needed to do that but showing convergence - for me - feels strange to "just" argue with that i.e $1/n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. Do you know if you can apply that you knw that $1/n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ to $1/n^2$, $1/n^3$ etc.?

Comment: i am not quite sure how that is related, but sure you can. just use the squeeze theorem, since $n^k\geq n\Longrightarrow 0\leq (1/n^k)\leq (1/n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.